# SQLMODEL background error with date object

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm trying to compare date objects using sqlmodel,fastapi,sqlalchemy. My ORM class looks like that:

```
class Evergreen(SQLModel,table=True):
    id_seq: Optional[int] = Field(default=None,primary_key=True)
    phase_end: Optional[date] = None
    phase_start: Optional[date] = None
    phase_type: Optional[str] = None
    software_product_version_name: Optional[str] = None
    product_name: Optional[str] = None
    software_product_version_id: Optional[int] = None
    product_id: int
```

and my function like this:

```
@app.get(
    "/products/",
    summary="Query all evergreen products",
    response_description="Successful Query",
    tags=[Tags.items]
)
def get_product_evergreen(product_id: Optional[int] = None,days_ago: Optional[int] = None ,session: Session = Depends(get_session)) -> list:
    query = select(Evergreen,Mapping.product_alias).where(Evergreen.product_id == Mapping.eim_product_id)
    if product_id:
        query = query.where(Mapping.eim_product_id == product_id)
    if days_ago:
        margin = date.today() - timedelta(days_ago)
        query = query.where(date.today() >= Evergreen.phase_end - margin)
    
    return session.exec(query).fetchall()
```

`Evergreen.phase_end` has `DATE` type in oracle which is my database on the backend. I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
[SQL: SELECT evergreen.id_seq, evergreen.phase_end, evergreen.phase_start, evergreen.phase_type, evergreen.software_product_version_name, evergreen.product_name, evergreen.software_product_version_id, evergreen.product_id, 
mapping.product_alias
FROM evergreen, mapping
WHERE evergreen.product_id = mapping.eim_product_id AND evergreen.phase_end - :phase_end_1 <= :param_1]
[parameters: {'phase_end_1': datetime.date(2022, 10, 26), 'param_1': datetime.date(2022, 11, 25)}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I don't understand why the database is expecting a number.

Comment: You're subtracting the margin (which is a date) from another date - that doesn't seem to make sense? Instead, resolve the range before querying - so that you end up with `.where(Evergreen.phase_end < range_start)` instead of subtracting dates inside your where statement. (it's a bit hard trying to follow the logic when you start subtracting dates and comparing them to today instead of what's in the database)

Comment: you're right. I also noticed that the database doesn't have a problem when I subtract a date from an integer , but python complains and I need to pass a `timedelta` object instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your query typing is wrong.

Try this,

```
    if days_ago:
        margin = date.today() - timedelta(days_ago)
        query = query.where(Evergreen.phase_end =< date.today() + margin)
```